# Checking for users who are member in on of groups, but not in one specific group

Tags: active-directory, powershell-2.0, user-management

Im looking for a way to identify users who are member of one of few groups (a,b,c) but also are not in a specific group (d), an exception group, to later on perform some tasks on them (filling in specific attribute based on value of samaccountname).

For now, I managed to list user accounts who are member of specific group and follow another condition of having smart card enforcement as false:

```bsh
$groups = "a","b","c"
foreach ($group in $groups) {
  Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group |
    Get-ADUser -Properties 'smartcardlogonrequired' |
    where {$_.smartcardlogonrequired -eq $false}
}
```

I thought of following.
Defining group of exceptions by

```bsh
$exceptions = (Get-ADGroup 'd').distinguishedname
foreach ($group in $groups) {
  Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group |
    Get-ADUser -Properties 'smartcardlogonrequired' |
    where {$_.smartcardlogonrequired -eq $false} |
    Get-ADUser –Filter {-not(memberof –eq $d}
}
```

However, it doesn't really do the trick, and im sure theres a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a list of the distinguished names of the members of group "d" and filter on users whose distinguished name is not part of that list:

```bsh
$exceptions = Get-ADGroupMember 'd' | Select-Object -Expand DistinguishedName
foreach ($group in $groups) {
  Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group |
    Get-ADUser -Properties 'smartcardlogonrequired' |
    Where-Object {
      $_.smartcardlogonrequired -eq $false -and
      $exceptions -notcontains $_.DistinguishedName
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Ansgar, would you happen to have a moment to chat with me in regards to a certain challenge ?:) Can I somehow contact you via email or some messanger?

Comment: Contact information can be found on my homepage (link is in my [SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171?tab=profile)).